# MVC 3 Tutorial help database operator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, operator-keyword

I was following this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store
when I stumbled on this piece of code.

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {

        // Retrieve the album from the database
        var addedAlbum = storeDB.Albums
            .Single(album => album.AlbumId == id);

        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        cart.AddToCart(addedAlbum);

        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I don't understand two things: 
**1)**
    var addedAlbum = storeDB.Albums
                .Single(album => album.AlbumId == id);

What is this code doing? I don't know what the operator => does. Also I guess .Single is some function for the database? 
**2)**
This function is having a call to itself? I don't see how it adds the album to the cart this way. Wouldn't this cause a function to go into an infinite loop?

Comment: You probably should start learning C# before getting into ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are a lot of core C# that you aren't quite familiar with yet.

the `=>` operator is the lambda operator, which is a succinct way of writing an inline function.

The `Single` function is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) which in this case is makes a call to the database.  This method makes use of a neat feature known as [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) to convert the strongly typed C# comparison into the corresponding SQL code.  How it works is a pretty advanced topic, so for now just consider it "magic".

The `AddToCart` method of the `cart` object is different from the `AddToCart` controller action method the code is currently in.  I don't have a link for that, since that's fairly basic object-oriented programming.

I would assume that `cart.AddToCart` will actually update the database.

Also read up on LINQ for a better understanding.  This is most likely either Linq To Sql or LINQ to Entities using the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The Action is being passed the ID of a album which can then be retrieved from the database with `storeDB.Albums.Single()` call. (the lambda is saying "find the entry in the database where the value in the AlbumId column matches the ID passed to the controller.") Think of `.Single` as the LINQ facsimile of:

```
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM   Albums
WHERE  Albums.AlbumId = <id>
```

It's then grabbing the user's shopping cart and adding that fetched album object to the cart.

Then you're redirected to the index where it can list all entries in the cart.